# How to use WASTED with xcode to optimize image size?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, archive, image-optimization

I'm attempting to use [WASTED](http://wasted.werk01.de/) on my app to decrease its size (currently at 839MB). I've followed the steps of integrating it into my xcode project archive scheme:

```
Edit your project scheme open the "Archive" scheme (or any other scheme you like)
Select "Post-actions"
Add a new "Run script action"
Enter open -a Wasted "${ARCHIVE_PATH}" into the script field
Now every time you archive your project, WASTED will automatically be opened and analyses your project.
```

When I archive it I get the pop up that asks me to perform the WASTED analysis.

[image]

Then I hit export and press the distribute button to create the ipa file. The problem is that the ipa is still displaying a size of >800MB. Am I missing something? I exported the xcarchive file to a different place (desktop) and left it there. Was I supposed to export it into my app? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Select export and and choose a destination, this will create a folder that contains compressed images inside a "payload" folder and a .csv file explaining what was done to the images. Now you can replace the images inside your project with the compressed images to save space.